# Docker Networking: Auto-discovering host names in a bridge network

Tags: docker

I am trying to get the following pretty basic (or so I thought) networking setup to work using Docker 1.9:

- I have multiple containers that run services, e.g. a `postgres` container and a `python` container (there might be more than two).
- Those containers are connected to each other through a `bridge` network.
- I want them to be addressable using unique host names (i.e. the Python container should be able to do `ping postgres` to ping the Postgres container).

Following the tutorial (https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/), I can use the following sequence of commands to achieve this:

```
#create the containers
docker run -itd --name container1 busybox
docker run -itd --name container2 busybox
#create the network
docker network create test
docker network connect test container1
docker network connect test container2
```

This works quite well and Docker correctly sets the entries in `etc/hosts` to point to the correct IP addresses. However, I also want to be able to run several instances of that setup (i.e. containers + network) simultaneously. This does not work because the entry for each container in the `/etc/hosts` file is equal to its **name**, which needs to be unique. Specifying the `hostname` parameter does not solve this problem since it only changes the **local** hostname of the container (i.e. the one it sees itself).

I would be very interested in a way to do this without resorting to having a DNS service running on a container. It seems to be a simple problem but unfortunately I was not able to find any configuration options to change the name of a container in the `/etc/hosts` file.

BTW, I want the hostname to be the same in every instance of my network+container setup so that I do not need to dynamically pass the hostnames into the container (e.g. to tell the Python container the address of the Postgres container)

**EDIT**: I did some research on Docker's issue tracker and there seems to be a feature for this in the pipeline: https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues/737

Comment: That is a very important question: [`--link <name or id>:alias`](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) (["Legacy links"](http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/#legacy-links)) allowed you to define an "alias" between two containers (managed by the same docker daemon). That alias could be reused by different `docker run`, allowing each container to see their own aliased linked container (with the same alias). I did not find the same feature with the new libnetwork.

Comment: yes I read about this as well, couldn't find a similar feature in 1.9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[docker 1.10, and PR 19242](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19242) can help:

```
docker create --net-alias=[]: Add network-scoped alias for the container
```

docker 1.10 has a new section [**Network-scoped alias**](https://github.com/mavenugo/docker/blob/dda513ef651b42fcb9625e651f664554161c0a6a/docs/userguide/networking/work-with-networks.md#network-scoped-alias):

> While links provide private name resolution that is localized within a container, the network-scoped alias provides a way for a container to be discovered by an alternate name by any other container within the scope of a particular network.
>   Unlike the link alias, which is defined by the consumer of a service, the network-scoped alias is defined by the container that is offering the service to the network.
>
> Continuing with the above example, create another container in `isolated_nw` with a network alias.

```
$ docker run --net=isolated_nw -itd --name=container6 --net-alias app busybox
8ebe6767c1e0361f27433090060b33200aac054a68476c3be87ef4005eb1df17
```

Now let us connect `container6` to the `local_alias` network with a different network-scoped alias.

```
$ docker network connect --alias scoped-app local_alias container6
```

> `container6` in this example now is aliased as `app` in network `isolated_nw` and as `scoped-app` in network `local_alias`.