# How to refer a host as hostname instead container name?

Tags: docker

I have two containers I've started as:

`-name foo --hostname mynet.foo`

`-name bar --hostname bar`

From `foo` container I can ping bar using `ping bar` but from `bar` container I only can ping `foo` container using `ping foo` (the container name). If I try to ping foo using `ping mynet.foo` I have a `bad address: mynet.foo`.

I need to refer the hosts as the `--hostname` value not the `-name` value.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835469/docker-networking-auto-discovering-host-names-in-a-bridge-network/34921289#34921289): the `--hostname` is the `local hostname of the container (i.e. the one it sees itself).` Insane!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access container's via their hostname you can simply add a host entry for that.

For example:

```
docker run -tid --name foo --add-host=bar:<ip-address-of-bar-container> -h  mynet.foo <image-name>

docker run -tid --name bar --add-host=mynet.foo:<ip-address-of-foo-container> -h bar <image-name>
```

With this you will be able to ping mynet.foo from bar container and vice-versa.

Comment: Wait.... how can I do this without know the IP address? Need I to create a complete DNS in the `run` command line? I can't even know the network IP range because I want to keep the things simple.

Comment: You can refer to this link for dns settings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242217/access-docker-container-from-host-using-containers-name/45071126#45071126

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks.